# Incomplete update of tex-common during 20.04.2 upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade

While performing an desktop upgrade from a  freshly-updated 18.04 to 20.04.2, a problem was reported related to the tex-common package. The upgrade seems to run ok except that the software updater always reports the problem, e.g.:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-70-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tex-common
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up tex-common (6.13) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... done.
Running mktexlsr /var/lib/texmf ... done.
Building format(s) --all.
    This may take some time... 
fmtutil failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/fmtutil.CLS3AAW1
```

I ran `dpkg -C` and got:

```
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 tex-common           common infrastructure for building and installing TeX
```

So I tried `dpkg --configure tex-common` and, with the exception of the extension on the output file, the report was a duplicate of the one above.

The output file ends with:

```
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfjadetex -progname=pdfjadetex *pdfjadetex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [ERROR]: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=jadetex -progname=jadetex *jadetex.ini </dev/null' return status: 1
fmtutil [ERROR]: returning error due to option --strict
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 12
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 2 (pdftex/pdfjadetex pdftex/jadetex)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 14
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 2
```

The entire file can be seen at https://www.dropbox.com/s/vz5u6lvkpxy0l9d/fmtutil.CLS3AAW1?dl=0

I have 3 other machines running 20.04.2, two of which were also upgrades from 18.04, and this problem did not occur on any of them, so it doesn't seem likely to me that it's a dpkg bug. Do I have any alternatives other than a clean reinstallation of 20.04.2?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall tex-common`

Comment: Not sure, but https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jadetex suggests you need package `texlive-formats-extra`.
Same for `pdfjadetex`.
I wouldn't know why one system fails and not the others.

Comment: Perhaps useful? https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531274-LaTeX-on-fresh-install

Comment: Installing texlive-formats-extra (and a number of other packages triggered by that) seems to have cleared things up. Thanks, @sancho.s!!

Comment: Great! I will post this as an answer so you can close the OP.

Answer (score 0):

[packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jadetex](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jadetex) suggests you need package `texlive-formats-extra`.
Same for `pdfjadetex`.
I wouldn't know why one system fails and not the others.